# Given a number check if digits form an equation with addition?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, math

Given a string *S*, I want to find out whether there are non-overlapping substrings *A*, *B* and *C* in *S*, so that the equation *A + B = C* holds when the substrings are interpreted as decimal numbers.

Example: For S = 17512, the answer is yes, because 12 + 5 = 17 holds.

This is not a homework question, I have tried approaching this problem building a suffix array

17512

7512

512

12

2

but then I realize that given 132,  1 + 2 = 3
Would require other forms of permutations in selection?

How do you solve this in an efficient way?

Comment: Could you also have 1 + 7 = 5 + 1 + 2?

Comment: do all digits have to be in the equation? Also, `12` is not a digit. Can you form numbers taking any digits in any order?

Comment: Yes 12 is not a digit , Multiple digits can be taken as well as long as a substring sums up with another substring to a substring in the result. i will edit the question

Comment: Looks what you need is more like an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), than reducing to the _'digits'_ ...

Comment: What about overlapping substrings? is 1+1=2 a valid equation for "12"? is 23+34=57 a valid equation for "23457"? Must all characters be used? is 1+2=3 a valid equation for "1234"?

Comment: No Overlapping Substrings . only distinct substrings.All characters need not be used

Comment: How large is the decimal representation of the number?

Comment: I updated the question, according to some of your comments. Please check whether it still reflects your original problem.

Comment: I also added a better algorithm for the simplified version to my answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Thank you so much , I have a clarification with a simpler version of my problem .I have updated my question to so that I can get an idea of the efficient way to solve that problem

Comment: @ashokv: You already have the answers you need. Check them out.

Comment: Let me go through them carefully, thanks @Niklas B

Comment: In what regard is the question still unclear after the edit?

Comment: Voting to reopen because the question has been edited to reflect all information given in comments, which makes the problem clear enough

Comment: @ashokv I added an O(n^3 log n) solution to my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let *S* be the decimal representation of the number. If *n = |S|* is small enough (<500 or so), you can use the following algorithm:

Let us enumerate A and C from the equation A + B = C (where we assume w.l.o.g. A > B). We know that they need to be of around the same size (plus/minus one digit), so enumerating the possibilities is a cubic operation (there are *O(n<sup>3</sup>)* candidates).

For every candidate pair *(A, C)*, we need to check whether `B = C - A` is in the string and not overlapping with any of the *A* or *C* substrings. We can compute the difference in linear time using arithmetics in base 10.

The tricky part is to check whether *B* is a substring not overlapping *A* or *C*. *A* and *C* split the string into 3 parts:

```
S = xAyCz
```

If we enumerate them in a clever way, with fixed start positions and decreasing size, we can maintain [suffix automata](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/suffixautmtn.html) of part x and the reverses of parts y and z.

Now we can check in linear time whether *B = C - A* (or its reverse) exists in one of the three parts.

Time complexity of this approach: *Θ(n<sup>4</sup>)*.

There is a variation of this which is slightly more complicated, but faster (thanks to Evgeny for pointing it out):

- Create a suffix tree of the input string. Every node represents a substring. Store in every node a balanced binary search tree of the positions where the substring occurs in the string. You might need persistent trees here to save time and space.
- Enumerate A and C, but this time starting from the least-significant digit (the rightmost end).
- While growing A and C from right to left, keep track of the result of B = C - A. It will also grow from least-significant to most-siginificant digit. Do a search for B in the suffix tree. You can do this one digit at a time, so you can make grow A and C by 1 digit, update B and locate it in the suffix tree in O(1).
- If B is positive, do three range queries in the BBST of positions to check whether B occurs in the string and does not overlap A or C

Runtime: *O(n<sup>3</sup> log n)*.

**UPDATE:** regarding the simplified version where all characters need to be used:

We first realize that we can do arithmetics on substrings of our string in linear time, if we work in base 10.

Now we want to find the splitting points *a < b*, so that your three substrings are *A = s<sub>1</sub>...s<sub>a</sub>*, *B = s<sub>a+1</sub>...s<sub>b</sub>* and *C = s<sub>b+1</sub>...s<sub>n</sub>*.

We can prove that there is only a constant number of candidates for *a* and *b*, because all three parts must have approximately the same size for the equation to hold.

Using arbitrary precision arithmetics, we can easily try out all candidate pairs (a,b) and for each of those, find *M = max(A,B,C)*. Then just check whether *M* is the sum of the other two numbers.

Total time complexity: *Θ(n)*.

Comment: This assumes all digits are used, which I don't think is part of the assumptions of the problem. It also assumes digits are used in contiguous subsets, which may or not be part of the assumptions of the problem.

Comment: @user2566092: Substring to me means "contiguous".

Comment: still you assume that all digits are used, which might not be what the OP intended.

Comment: @user2566092 quote from a comment: "All characters need not be used"

Comment: ok so we're in agreement, OP doesn't need all characters to be used but your solution assumes that all characters are used.

Comment: @user2566092 Lulz I seem to have reading problems. That indeed makes the problem more interesting

Comment: @user2566092: Fixed it now

Comment: Nice approach. But why only O(n^4)? Isn't it possible to grow both A and C, compute their difference, and find the result in suffix tree, all this in one pass?

Comment: @Evgeny yes maybe this is even possible to implement in O(n^3). I've never thought about whether a search point in the automaton would remain valid after we append to the automaton. Also on some points we might get carries so that B gets changed altogether between iterations. But I guess that can be amortized away

Comment: `B` cannot change altogether if `C-A` is computed backwards, starting from least significant digit. And, I think, a single static suffix tree is simpler than 3 growing DAWGs (each node of this tree may be augmented with some function of indexes of descendant leaves to control overlapping).

Comment: @Evgeny what you suggest seems sensible. This would replace one factor of n by log n for range queries in the BSTs of positions. I still think we can get carries, no matter how we grow A and C, but that should be fine

Comment: @Evgeny oh of course you right about the carries, they only affect the higher digits

Comment: @EvgenyKluev I incorporated your approach as an alternative algorithm (I feel it is slightly more complicated due to the incremental computation of B, the range queries we need to do and because the index sets will probably need to be represented by persistent trees, maybe there is a trick to avoid that)

Comment: Actually we can get rid of log(N) factor and BBST. Just augment each node with 3 values: boolean b{if there is any leaf in "x"}, int p{max leaf index in "Ay"}, int q{max leaf index}. Then check if (b|p>A.end|q>C.end) instead of range query. And one more improvement: we could obtain O(1) expected time for random strings with simple preprocessing.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev Actually I'm not quite so sure after thinking about it: A and C will grow to the left, so the max would decrease during the execution of the algorithm after we picked the end positions of A and C. Since we incrementally walk down the tree we can probably fix that by decreasing pointers, but it's also not too simple

Comment: No, maximums cannot change. One of them belongs to interval "Ay" (between positions of least-significant digits of A and C), this interval is static, its ends does not move. Other belongs to entire tree. So the only time we need to adjust maximums is when we move A or C (only N^2 updates).

Comment: @EvgenyKluev: While we grow A and C, `y` shrinks, for example. It is the range between least-significant digit of A and *most-significant* digit of C

Comment: `y` shrinks, `A` grows, but whole interval remains unchanged.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev: But if we grow A to the right, we cannot build B from least-significant to most-significant. We need to grow A and C from right to left, at least that's how I thought it would work best. But I think you're right, in that case we just need a suffix tree of the reverse of S, then the augmentation works

Comment: @EvgenyKluev: Yes, it wasn't meant that way, but that makes sense :P

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't see it working"? Also it's not necessary to build suffix tree N^2 times. Once is enough.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev: The problem is that B grows into the direction in which A and C grow, so in the reversed string we need for every part the *minimum* position of a leaf, but that changes while A and C grow. Correct me if I'm wrong. Maybe it would work with an augmented DAWG instead of suffix tree. Or maybe I'm just not thinking correctly right now.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood you, but A, B, and C all should grow in the same direction. And we need *maximum* position just to check if there is at least one non-overlapping substring. No idea how to augment DAWG, probably impossible, to augment we need to start with as many leaves as elements in the array.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev: What do you mean by "position"? Because by position I mean the starting positions of the suffixes represented by a subtree, and then we need the minimum (leftmost) position to ensure that we have as much space as possible. Say S = xAyCz (least-significant digits leftmost, A,B and C growing to the right) then we need to find the leftmost, not rightmost match of B in the part y, or am I missing something? The rightmost match might overlap with C

Comment: By "position" I mean only starting index of `B`. Because that's what we search in suffix tree. That's why I'm talking about maximum (rightmost in the reversed array) position.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev: Yeah but the maximum doesn't cut it. Let's say we have `reverse(S) = xAsysCz`. `s` are the matches, i.e. possible starting positions of `B`. The rightmost of those overlaps with C. The leftmost is the one we need, but it gets invalidates as soon as A grows one step more towards the right.

Comment: You are right, I missed this point, sorry. Possibly this could be fixed but I don't see any way right now. Other alternative is to use suffix tree with deletions (as explained in [CodeChef editorial](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/23739/tmp01-editorial)). This gives O(N^3) algorithm complexity and linear space. Btw, how do you intend to use persistence? That's far from obvious. And without it BBST variant has quadratic space requirements, which is not so good.

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to form substrings from arbtirary subsets of digits in their original given order as long as your digits don't overlap in the 2 summands and the sum, then I believe your problem is NP-complete. I think this is even true if the target sum is given and all you have to do is find two non-overlapping substrings of digits that add up to the target sum. However I don't have a proof of NP-completeness yet.

If your substrings of digits have to be consecutive then the situation is much better. You can search over all combinations of 2 summands and 1 sum for the starting and ending points of the numbers in O(n^6) time, and certainly there are improvements that can be made because e.g. for a given target sum, you only need to search over pairs of substrings whose max length adds up to the length of your target sum either exactly or minus 1.

UPDATE: If you need to find 3 non-overlapping contiguous substrings that give you the summation formula, then you can hash all O(n^2) substring values and then hash the sum of all pairs of summands to see if the target sum is in your hash table. If so, then you only need to check if the summand beginning and ending indices do not overlap the summand indices. Worst-case time is O(n^6), expected running time is O(n^5) for random inputs.

Comment: @NiklasB. I'm assuming constant time arithmetic and hashing, which may not be a valid assumption. Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (As in both your examples) that your 3 substrings are contiguous, non-overlapping, non-negative, and between them cover the whole input, then there is a quadratic time solution.

- First (temporarily) assume the order is aaabbbccc where aaa+bbb=ccc, and aaa>bbb.
- The length of ccc must either be the same as aaa or at most one larger.
- So the length of aaa (len_a) must be between n/3 and n/2.
- Given the len_a, there are two choices for len_c --- len_a or len_a+1.
- Given these, there is only one possible length of bbb. len_b = n-len_a = len_c
- Test these 2(n/2 - n/3) = n/3 cases.
- Each test is O(n) cost due to string to int conversion.

Repeat the above analysis for two permutations (aaa>bbb v bbb>=aaa), times three permutations (aaa+bbb=ccc v aaa+ccc=bbb v bbb+ccc=aaa)

You could improve the test to check only the most (or least) significant i digits of the three numbers, returning early if the sum was not possible. Assuming randomly distributed digits, you might be able to show that the expected run time of such a test was constant.
This would turn the whole algorithm into an O(n) runtime.

Comment: "between them cover the whole input" is unfortunately not the case. I also thought that at first :(

Comment: Also you assume constant-time arithmetics, but that is unlikely to be available when the string is beyond the word size

Comment: I don't assume constant time arithmetic. I assume O(n) cost of testing each equality case. This covers both string to int conversion and arithmetic costs. In any case I probably wouldn't convert to an int representation, but do the maths in the string domain. In the case of amortised constant test option, I believe the arithmetic costs grow the same as the string to int conversion costs i.e. amortised constant.